# Can't login with python post error shows up

Tags: python, python-requests

When I try to login into GameStop(gamestop.ca) with requests, this is what I get. What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? I tried adding many other headers including the authority header shown in chrome dev tool under network. I don't understand why this doesn't work but selenium works when I try logging in with selenium. If this is because of bot detection, isn't selenium supposed to be detected much more easily?

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
    'UserName': '*****',
    'Password': '******',
    'RememberMe': 'false'
}
with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.post('https://www.gamestop.ca/Account/LogOn', headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
print(r.text)
```

```
403
b'<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;gamestop&#46;ca&#47;Account&#47;LogOn" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;70fd017&#46;1635453520&#46;211da9c5\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;gamestop&#46;ca&#47;Account&#47;LogOn" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;70fd017&#46;1635453520&#46;211da9c5
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct authentication method and key names? Are you sure you are posting to the correct endpoint with your credentials?